# Border inside Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid that represents the tic-tac-toe game. I wanted to put an border only inside the grid. Today, I proceed in this way:

```css
:root {
  --border: 2px dashed #393939;
  --symbol-color: #FF7F5B;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  color: var(--symbol-color);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.child:nth-child(1),
.child:nth-child(2),
.child:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(7),
.child:nth-child(8),
.child:nth-child(9) {
  border-top: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(1),
.child:nth-child(4),
.child:nth-child(7) {
  border-right: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(3),
.child:nth-child(6),
.child:nth-child(9) {
  border-left: var(--border);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

This solution works but I find it unattractive. Do you have an idea to refactor this solution?

Comment: given snippet is not working. missed any css??

Comment: I just copy / paste the interesting part of my problem, the snippets do not work because it misses the grid container. The HTML I copied in my post is an output of ReactJS. My main problem is to find a CSS factorization to put borders in the same way as it is shown in my screenshot. Thank you for your interest in my post!

Comment: There is no `align-content` flex container property. I guess you meant `justify-content`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing you can use the `nth-child` selector in a better way like below instead of targeting one by one.

```css
.child:nth-child(-n+3) {
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-right: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(3n) {
  border-left: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(n+7) {
  border-top: var(--border);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --border: 2px dashed #393939;
  --symbol-color: #FF7F5B;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  color: var(--symbol-color);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.child:nth-child(-n+3) {
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-right: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(3n) {
  border-left: var(--border);
}

.child:nth-child(n+7) {
  border-top: var(--border);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26):

Since you want a stylized border (dashed, in this case), then your approach and the approach taken in the other answers appears to be useful.

However, if you decide to use a simple, solid line border, then the approach can be simplified. Just use the background color of the grid for border color, and the `grid-gap` property for border width.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background-color: black;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FF7F5B;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

body { margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">X</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">O</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, for this solution, I need stylized border however, I did not know your solution for simple borders! I keep it in mind for next time, thank you!

Comment: I do prefer this solution, and using a diagonally striped background would give you your dashes... https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Comment: You could always have a background image in the main .grid div with dots for you to achieve the desired effect using this approach

Answer (score 5):

You can reduce number of `nth-child` selector here from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49554993/1548895).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  --border: 2px dashed #393939;
  --symbol-color: #FF7F5B;
}

.grid {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: var(--symbol-color);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.child:not(:nth-child(3n)) {
  border-right: var(--border);
}

.child:not(:nth-last-child(-n + 3)) {
  border-bottom: var(--border);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">x</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">o</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may consider this workaround.

You may use grid-template-columns to do the trick.

- create a parent container that will hold your four images.
- set a background color (desire color of the border).
- set the padding to 0
- then do the trick arrange the images by grid-template-column: auto
  auto;
- then add gap to them grid-gap: 10px; (to show the background color of
  the container as grid).

*please see code below for reference*

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;

  background-color: #000;
  padding: 0;
}
.container > div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
      <div>Image here</div>
      <div>Image Here</div>
      <div>Image here</div>
      <div>Image here</div>
    </div>
```

to help you visualize i create a sample code

http://plnkr.co/edit/gIeumXLt0k3FPVCgGlDd?p=preview

Hope it helps

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of negative margin in `.child` class with `overflow:hidden` in parent `.grid` class here...No need to use `nth-child` selector here...

```css
:root {
  --border: 2px dashed #393939;
  --symbol-color: #FF7F5B;
}

.grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, calc(100%/3));
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  color: var(--symbol-color);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border-bottom: var(--border);
  border-left: var(--border);
  margin-left: -2px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The nth-child selectors seem more understandable for code review than tricks with negative margins and overflow hidden. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

What about using `background` and `linear-gradient`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  --b: #393939 0px, #393939 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 8px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(100% / 3));
  grid-auto-rows:calc(100% / 3);
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right ,var(--b)) 0   calc(100% / 3), 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,var(--b)) calc(2 * (100% / 3)) 0, 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right ,var(--b)) 0 calc(2 * (100% / 3)), 
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,var(--b)) calc(100% / 3) 0;
  background-size:100% 2px,2px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child">A</div>
  <div class="child">B</div>
  <div class="child">C</div>
  <div class="child">D</div>
  <div class="child">E</div>
  <div class="child">F</div>
  <div class="child">G</div>
  <div class="child">H</div>
  <div class="child">I</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not think that this solution is very pretty but I thank you for your answer, I will look at it !

Answer (score 0):

Im a bit late for that question but have a solution.
Each child must have the border-right and border-bottom set.
The parent div have pseudo over the edge border to mimic a removal.
It only works if you use this on a plain background-color.

In my example, background is white.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="child">A</div>
  <div class="child">B</div>
  <div class="child">C</div>
  <div class="child">D</div>
  <div class="child">E</div>
  <div class="child">F</div>
  <div class="child">G</div>
  <div class="child">H</div>
  <div class="child">I</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid{ display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; position: relative; }
.grid:before{ border-right: 1px solid #fff; content: ''; display: block; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute; }
.grid:after{ border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; content: ''; display: block; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute;  }
.child{ border: 1px solid #000; border-width: 0 1px 1px 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :)

https://codepen.io/atnesness/pen/dyQabBM

main hack is in this code. Not that (6) should be replaced with the max amount of columns in your page

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  @container (min-width: #{$i * $cardWidth}px) {
    .summary__item:nth-child(n):before {
       display: block;
    }
    
    .summary__item:nth-child(n):after {
      display: none;
    }

    .summary__item:nth-child(#{$i}n):before {
       display: none;
    }
    
    .summary__item:nth-child(#{$i}n):after {
      display: block;
      content: '';

      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      
      transform: translateY(#{$cardHeight - $cardPadding * 2}px);

      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      background: black;
    }
  }
}


.summary .summary__item:last-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.summary .summary__item:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is not a 3x3 tic-tac-toe table